# GCP Cloud Firestore for server communication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have all back-end services on **GCP**. Can we use Cloud firestore to communicate to our server rather than using HTTP request from the app?

***Eg:*** Lets say I have a POST HTTP request which stores data to Big Query. Rather then making a post request from app, why can't I make the app store the data in Firestore & then pull that data via Cloud functions triggers & push it to Big Query.

PS : Just here to ask if this idea is good or is there a downside to it?

Comment: I use this method all the time to fetch external resources and store them in my project's own Cloud Storage or to run manual administration "cron jobs". I don't see why you couldn't adapt it to BigQuery.

Comment: It's a good idea if it works for you. We don't have enough information to know if that's going to be the case. Stack Overflow isn't a very good forum for soliciting general advice.  If you want to have a discussion about stuff like this, I suggest posted to a discussion board such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the reply. I have added question to reddit.https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/ehi5n3/gcp_cloud_firestore_for_server_communication/